# ChartJS doesnt display labels provided by Jinja variable

Tags: flask, chart.js, jinja2

I would like to use Flask to render a ChartJS graph. This is from my routes.py

```
@app.route("/graph")
def graph():
    d = Eval.query.all()
    labels = [i.date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for i in d]
    data = [i.bw for i in d]
    return render_template('chart.html', title='Charts', labels = labels, data = data)
```

I've the following code in the chart.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<canvas id="myChart" height="400" width="800"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
  labels: ['16.07.2017', '23.07.2017', '30.07.2017', '06.08.2017', '13.08.2017'],
  datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: {{ data }} 
   }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive:false
   }
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

with this code the chart is rendered with the correct labels.

**Question:**

However once I change the labels to

```
 labels: {{ labels }}
```

the chart is not rendered at all.

I checked to make sure that the {{ labels }} expression is indeed also a list with the correct formating. Calling {{ labels }} above the script tag shows the following output in the html page:

```
['16.07.2017', '23.07.2017', '30.07.2017', '06.08.2017', '13.08.2017']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using `safe` filter special symbols would be escaped during template parsing process and would corrupt the variable value.

In the case above, final variable value without 'jinja safe' filter would be

```
["16.07.2017", "23.07.2017"] =>[&#39;16.07.2017&#39;,&#39;23.07.2017&#39;]
```

And that value (`[&#39;16.07.2017&#39;,&#39;23.07.2017&#39;]`) is illegal for JS and you'll be able to see the error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

In the case above, final variable value with 'jinja safe' filter would be the same

```
["16.07.2017", "23.07.2017"] =>["16.07.2017", "23.07.2017"]
```

[You can read more about escaping here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#controlling-autoescaping).

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var dates = {{labels|safe}};
var data1 = {{data|safe}}
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
      labels: dates,
      datasets: [{
          label: "My First dataset",
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          data: data1
```

I added the Jinja expressions as variables inside the script and now the chart renders as expected. Still not sure why ...